# SIMPLE SQL SELECT INTO GRAPH

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, select, graph

I am having trouble outputting an SQL Select Statement to my XML to be used for my Graph

I have these results

`December 2011`   `470` `FRESENIUS`

`January 2012`   `434`  `FRESENIUS`

`February 2012` `278`   `FRESENIUS`

`February 2012` `2` `STORESID`

I need to output them like this so I can loop my Code and generate the XML

`Month Year` `FRESNIUS` `STORESID`

`December 2011`   `470` `0`

`January 2012`   `434`  `0`

`February 2012` `278`   `2`

take note i did not include the headers, these are all column results.
and also, STORESID and FRESNIUS are not STATIC Values. Multiple Storers Exists so I needed to Expand my number of Columns also , Dynamically.

I kinda need to output the second one to generate the XML properly thru PHP which I already have. Or are there any other proper way.

Thanks.

query below for the output i was talking about

```
SELECT  
        DATENAME(month, orderdate)  + ' ' + CAST(Year(orderdate) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS 'Month Year' ,
        count(*) 'Number of Orders', 
        storerkey
FROM    orders
GROUP BY
        storerkey,
        DATENAME(month, orderdate) + ' ' +  CAST(Year(orderdate) AS VARCHAR(4)),
        CAST(Year(orderdate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(Month(orderdate) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
ORDER BY    
        storerkey,
        CAST(Year(orderdate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(Month(orderdate) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% certain of the XML output you need but you can take advantage of [SQL-Servers FOR XML clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190922.aspx) and PIVOT function. This should get you started:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (GraphDate DATETIME, Value INT, Type VARCHAR(50))
INSERT #Test VALUES 
    ('01/12/2011', 470, 'FRESENIUS'),
    ('01/01/2012', 434, 'FRESENIUS'),
    ('01/12/2012', 278, 'FRESENIUS'),
    ('01/02/2012', 2, 'STORESID')

SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR, GraphDate) [Year], 
        DATENAME(MONTH, GraphDate) [Month], 
        ISNULL(FRESENIUS, 0) [FRESENIUS],
        ISNULL(STORESID, 0) [STORESID]
FROM    #Test
        PIVOT
        (   SUM(Value)
            FOR Type IN ([FRESENIUS], [STORESID])
        ) PivotTable
FOR XML PATH('row'), ROOT

DROP TABLE #Test
```

---

**EDIT**

The below is the basic query you have asked for based on the query you have given.

```
SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, OrderDate)  + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, OrderDate) [MonthYear], 
        ISNULL(FRESENIUS, 0) [FRESENIUS],
        ISNULL(STORESID, 0) [STORESID]
FROM    Orders
        PIVOT
        (   COUNT(StorerKey)
            FOR StorerKey IN ([FRESENIUS], [STORESID])
        ) PivotTable
ORDER BY  DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate), DATEPART(MONTH, OrderDate)
```

---

**EDIT 2**

I don't think `PIVOT` is supported by SQL-Server 2000. You will need to use aggregate functions:

```
SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, OrderDate)  + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, OrderDate) [MonthYear], 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN StorerKey = 'FRESENIUS' THEN 1 END) [FRESENIUS],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN StorerKey = 'STORESID' THEN 1 END) [STORESID]
FROM    Orders
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate), DATEPART(MONTH, OrderDate), DATENAME(YEAR, OrderDate), DATENAME(MONTH, OrderDate)
ORDER BY  DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate), DATEPART(MONTH, OrderDate)
```

I think some `FOR XML` functionality is still available though so you may still be able to output your XML directly from SQL.

---

**EDIT 3**

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(2000)
SELECT  @SQL = ISNULL(@SQL, '') + ', COUNT(CASE WHEN StorerKey = ''' + StorerKey + ''' THEN 1 END) [' + StorerKey + ']'
FROM    (   SELECT  DISTINCT StorerKey
            FROM    Orders
        ) Keys


SET @SQL = 'SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, OrderDate) + '' '' + DATENAME(YEAR, OrderDate) [MonthYear]' + @SQL + 
            ' FROM    Orders
            GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate), DATEPART(MONTH, OrderDate), DATENAME(YEAR, OrderDate), DATENAME(MONTH, OrderDate)
            ORDER BY  DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate), DATEPART(MONTH, OrderDate)'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Comment: Added an edit. I don't think the `PIVOT` is supported by MSSQL 2000 so I've added an alternative (edit 2).

Comment: EDIT 2 works. but only and only if the STORESID and FRESNIUS are the columns. i forgot to mention that I would use this to different Procedures not just focusing on Orders Table. and Different Clients have different storerskey .

Comment: If you will have different StorerKeys then you need to add additional lines to the select statement in Edit 2 (.e.g. COUNT(CASE WHEN StorerKey = 'NewStorerKey' THEN 1 END) [NewStorerKey]. Alternatively, I have added a 3rd Edit, which will dynamically create your select statement based on the different storerkeys in your order table and then execute this dynamically created statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could join the table to itself. If I make assumptions about the column names, assume that either the FRESNIUS or STORESID could be absent, and use common table expressions (untested!):

```
WITH date_fresnius AS (
    SELECT [Month Year], FRESNIUS
    FROM original_table
)
, date_storesid AS (
    SELECT [Month Year], STORESID
    FROM original_table
)
SELECT
      ISNULL( f.[Month Year], s.[Month Year]) AS [Month Year]
    , ISNULL( f.FRESNIUS, 0 ) AS FRESNIUS
    , ISNULL( s.STORESID, 0 ) AS STORESID
FROM
    date_fresnius f
    FULL OUTER JOIN date_storesid s ON (f.[Month Year] = s.[Month Year])
```

If you always have a FRESNIUS record you can use a LEFT JOIN instead.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your query:

```
SELECT
    DATENAME(MONTH, orderdate) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(orderdate) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS [Month Year]
    COUNT(CASE storerkey WHEN 'FRESNIUS' THEN 1 END) AS FRESNIUS,
    COUNT(CASE storerkey WHEN 'STORESID' THEN 1 END) AS STORESID
FROM orders
GROUP BY YEAR(orderdate), MONTH(orderdate), DATENAME(MONTH, orderdate)
ORDER BY YEAR(orderdate), MONTH(orderdate)
```

Output:

```
Month Year      FRESNIUS   STORESID
December 2011        470          0
January 2012         434          0
February 2012        278          2
```

Comment: Works but only and only if the STORESID and FRESNIUS are the needed columns. i forgot to mention that I would use this to different Procedures not just focusing on Orders Table. and Different Clients have different storerskey. I can also have multiple storers that is why I am doing it this way instead.